# Форматирование стектрейса

Tags: php, yii2

Очень раздражают плохочитабельные стектрейсы. Я бы хотел:

1. Автоматически обрезать часть пути которая ведет к проекту. Т.е. все что до папки проекта. Я итак знаю где он лежит. А это мне только удлинняет итак огромную кучу текста.
2. Автоматически отфильтровывать ошибки которые ведут в папку vendor. Т.е. те ошибки которые прокинулись из библиотек. В большинстве случаев все-таки ошибка то не в библиотеке, а в пользовательском коде. Поэтому эти элементы стектрейса тоже бесполезны и удлинняют текст.
3. Автоматически обрезать слишком длинные строки. Пример: у меня в базе хранится HTML (да может это плохая практика, но так есть) и у меня вылетела ошибка при вставке. Мне в консоль выбивает помимо стектрейса еще выполненный SQL, а в нем как раз вставленные данные, в т.ч. HTML которые занимает дохрена места и забивает мне всю консоль (он длинный). Мне его смотреть в консоли как-то особо не надо. Из-за него я уже не вижу что мне перед этим писало потому что выше оно не мотает (корявая консоль под виндой).

Возможно ли это как-то реализовать? Может есть какие-то параметры логирования?

Comment: Перед выводом куда-либо вы можете обработать строку от debug_stacktrace по своему усмотрению.

Comment: Я сам никуда не вывожу. Оно само пишет ошибку мне.

Comment: Тогда только если вы измените код модуля отладки и перекомпилируете его.